# Set Toggle Button value on custom ribbon tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom ribbon with a few toggle buttons. I would like the buttons to be pressed on when i open the workbook. Is there a way to reference the toggle button, and set the value to True?

Comment: How did you create the ribbon: Visual Designer or the Ribbon xml customization?

Comment: Using RibbonX Visual Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

- From the RibbonX Designer, select your Toggle Button;
- In the Callbacks tab, check `getPressed`;
- If desired, edit the name of the callback procedure;
- Go to the Callback VBA Stubs tab;
- Copy the sub whose name corresponds to the one you've associated with the `getPressed` callback;
- Paste the code in e.g. Notepad for reference;
- Click Save;
- Open your workbook and go to the VBA editor;
- Copy & paste the code into a Module;
- Within the procedure, set `returnedVal = True`.

**Note**: getPressed is called when your ribbon is first rendered and whenever it is invalidated. In the procedure above, you should properly maintain the value you assign to `returnedVal`; instead of systematically returning `True`, return `True` initially, but return the actual pressed state of the toggle button afterwards.

**Example**:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_bIsToggleButton1Pressed As Boolean

Public Sub Togglebutton1_getPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = m_bIsToggleButton1Pressed
End Sub

Public Sub Togglebutton1_onAction(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef cancelDefault)
    m_bIsToggleButton1Pressed = Not m_bIsToggleButton1Pressed
End Sub

'This procedure is associated to the onLoad callback of the customUI root
'node in the Ribbon Designer.
Public Sub Test_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    m_bIsToggleButton1Pressed = True
End Sub
```